# Android phonegap access jarfile

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm just getting started using phonegap. I have some implemented libraries (jars) and I want to access them through javascript. I've been looking for an example to do this but I didn't find any. If you know any link or tutorial that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt3) that shows how to use a Barcode Scanner library with a plugin for a PhoneGap app. (Note that it is written for PhoneGap 1.4.1, so you'd have to make appropriate namespace changes if you use a more recent PhoneGap/Cordova version.)